# Insheet Using Relative File Name in Stata? (Or Wildcard in Filename?)

Tags: stata

I am curious and have not been able to find the answer to this question.

Is there a way to use a wildcard in a filename in Stata when using the insheet command?

For example, I have a .do file that I will use once a month. The name of the file will change every month(will include a date) but will have one part that will stay consistent(mmddyyyy_data.csv / data.csv stays consistent).

I haven't had any luck using insheet using "./*data.csv" Is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will not work because `insheet` only wants one dataset and the wildcard would allow you to return more than one.

If you're certain that there will only be one file of this type maybe you can use something like this:

```
local file : dir . files "*data.csv"
insheet using `file'
```

Comment: I agree. Another way to get a list of files is using `fs` from SSC.

Comment: insheet using `file' results in "invalid file specification."

I think that idea is on the right track though!

Comment: You can see what's going on by using `mac list` to see a list of the local macros and then seeing why the file name would be invalid or `set trace on` to see exactly the steps that Stata is going through up to the error

Comment: I think you may want to take out the `./` and that could do the trick, I have updated my answer to reflect this